# SVGAnnotation to create tool tips for each value in R heatmaps

Tags: r, svg, heatmap

I'd like to create a heat map in R that I want to use on a website. I stumbled upon the SVGAnnotation package which seems to be very nice to process SVG graphics in R to make them more interactive. First, I was planning to add tool tips for each cell in the heatmap - if the user hovers over the cell, the value of this cell should pop up. However, I am fighting with SVGAnnotation for more than 3 hours now, reading and trying things, and I can't get it to work.

I would appreciate any help on the SVGAnnotation tool tip function. But I would also very much appreciate alternatives to SVGAnnotation to add some activity to my R SVG heatmap.

So, what I have got so far looks like this:

```
    library(SVGAnnotation)
    data(mtcars)
    cars <- as.matrix(mtcars)

    map <- svgPlot(heatmap(cars))

    addToolTips(map, ...)   # problem

    saveXML(map, "cars.svg")
```

My problem is the addToolTips function itself, I guess. Intuitively, I would simply insert the data matrix, i.e., `cars`, but this does not work and R gets stuck (it's calculating, but doesn't return anything, I waited 50 minutes)

EDIT:
After some more online research, I found a good example of what I want to achieve: http://online.wsj.com/article/SB125993225142676615.html#articleTabs=interactive

This heat map looks really great, and the interactive features (tool tips) work very well. I am wondering how they did that. To me, it looks like the graphic was done in R using the ggplot package.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found another package, called `gridSVG` which seems to create tool tips as well. However, I cannot find any documentation/tutorial of how I could do it, information seems to be very sparse.

Comment: [Here's an article about `gridSVG`](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/gridSVG/gridsvg.pdf) from [Paul Murrel's homepage](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/). (Paul is the author of **grid** graphics and much of R's base graphics engine.)

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile I wrote my own external program to add the tool tips to an svg, but I will leave this question open, if someone could answer this it might also be useful for other people.

Comment: If it would be appropriate to post your solution as an answer (e.g. if it's a script that works with R), please do so. I at least would be really interested to see what you came up with!

Comment: I did it in Python - it is much more convenient for me. Basically, it is just a script that reads in a data matrix (can be the original one used to create the graphic in R) and puts tool tip title tags in the svg lines which represent the heatmap cells. The values from the data matrix are added to those "titles" then. It is very easy to accomplish, because the heatmap cells in the svg are in a particular order: bottom left corner to top right corner.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for adding that explanation.

Comment: The first time when you open a SVG created by the `svg()` funtion in R, it looks very confusing. But after some playing around (deleting elements and see what happens to the `svg`), I found out that, for example, for heat maps, you will find the `<path style...>` block, which contains the individual cells, approx. in the middle of the document starting after `<g id="surface6...>`

Comment: Then, you have to add `<g><title>tool tip text</title>` before and `</g>` after each of the `<path style.../>` tags to create the tool tips. Here, you can just write a script in your favorite language to automatize this process.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a command line tool that can do exactly that if you are still interested to add tool tips to your heat map. It runs in Windows/Linux/MacOS terminals. All you need as input is the heat map as svg file and the data table/matrix that you used as input to create your heat map as csv or other text file.